# how to select an element from 'data-formatted' tag using selenium wedriver

Tags: html, selenium

I have a series of elements as:

```
<li data-formatted="12:00am" data-minutes="0">12:00am</li>
<li data-formatted="1:00am" data-minutes="10">1:00am</li>
<li data-formatted="2:00am" data-minutes="20">2:00am</li>
.
.
<li data-formatted="12:00pm" data-minutes="80">12:00pm</li>
```

The issue I face is of finding any one of the element from this list of li. I can use driver.findElements() only when I am atleast able to identify it using any property tag since it does not have any like name, css or id.

Any suggestions on how to find an element using data-formatted tag would be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: you can definitely use like driver.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

Comment: Css attribute selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 0):

You can use CssSelector or XPath to find them.

Here are example expressions to find `li` element which has attribute `data-formatted` and the attribute contains "m":

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("li[data-formatted*='m']"));

driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[contains(@data-formatted, 'm')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select elements with data attributes through `querySelectorAll()` API and access all element's data attributes directly with vanilla JS standard dataset API.

In your case, to get the elements with `data-formatted` attribute you may do like

```
var formettedEls = document.querySelectorAll("[data-formatted]");
```

or

```
var El1AM = document.querySelectorAll("[data-formatted = '1:00am']");
```

or as another option you can search among the `formattedEls` for your specific one through the dataset API like

```
function findData(set, searchDataProp, searchData){
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(set, function(el){
                                      (el.dataset[searchDataProp] == searchData) && console.log(el.dataset[searchDataProp], searchData);
                                    });
}
findData(formattedEls, "formatted", "12:00am");
```